# How do i parse my array to my model

Tags: c#, arrays, json, parsing, model

I have made a ajax post and stringifyed my json and send the data to my controller method:
The data that the controller recieves looks like this:

"[\"0041300201\",1610612764,\"WAS\",\"Washington\",2772,\"Trevor Ariza\",\"F\",\"\",\"37:20\",7,10,0.7,6,6,1,2,4,0.5,1,5,6,2,1,0,0,3,22,18]"

My controller method:

```
public void addBoxScore(string playerstats) 
    {
       Games gamestats = new Games();
       gamestats.GAME_ID = playerstats[0];
       gamestats.TEAM_ID = playerstats[1];
       gamestats.TEAM_ABBREVIATION = playerstats[2].ToString();
       gamestats.TEAM_CITY = playerstats[3].ToString();
       gamestats.PLAYER_ID = playerstats[4];
       gamestats.PLAYER_NAME = playerstats[5].ToString();
       gamestats.START_POSITION = playerstats[6].ToString();
       gamestats.COMMENT = playerstats[7].ToString();

       gamestats.MIN = playerstats[8];
       gamestats.FGM = playerstats[9];
       gamestats.FGA = playerstats[10];
       gamestats.FG_PCT = playerstats[11];
       gamestats.FGTHREEM = playerstats[12];
       gamestats.FGTHREEA = playerstats[13];
       gamestats.FGTHREE_PCT = playerstats[14];
       gamestats.FTM = playerstats[15];
       gamestats.FTA = playerstats[16];
       gamestats.FT_PCT = playerstats[17];
       gamestats.OREB = playerstats[18];
       gamestats.DREB = playerstats[19];
       gamestats.REB = playerstats[20];
       gamestats.AST = playerstats[21];
       gamestats.STL = playerstats[22];
       gamestats.BLK = playerstats[23];
       gamestats.TO = playerstats[24];
       gamestats.PF = playerstats[25];
       gamestats.PTS = playerstats[26];
       gamestats.PLUS_MINUS = playerstats[27];


    }
```

When i do this the  gamestats.Game_ID becomes "91" instead of "0041300201" as i wanted it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this array or list of string instead of only strings. like this

```
public void addBoxScore(string[] playerstats)
```

Comment: Yes that works in some way. It puts it into an array. It still get \ in all the strings. Why is that?

Comment: It does realy just put the long string inside an array so there is one string in the array. Doesn't realy help me in this case.

Comment: can you paste the value of playerstats here? and also set your content type to applicaion/json(not sure the correct string, just google it, it should be there)

Comment: try something like this $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: 'http://localhost:16329/Hello',
    data: { name: 'norm' },
    dataType: 'json'
});

Comment: the value of playerstats is in the question
"[\"0041300201\",1610612764,\"WAS\",\"Washington\",2772,\"Trevor Ariza\",\"F\",\"\",\"37:20\",7,10,0.7,6,6,1,2,4,0.5,1,5,6,2,1,0,0,3,22,18]"

If i put contentType: "application/json" in the ajax then the controller recieves null :(

Comment: can you post your jquery code here? your data parameter name has to match exactly with parameter name in controller. In your case it should be data: { playerstats: yourjsondata },

Comment: data: { playerstats: JSON.stringify(playerstats) },